# Wordpress comments not showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Immaking my first theme and Im trying to show comments on the post, but for some reason its not working.

This is single.php:

```
comments_template();        //SOmeone said its necessary...

echo get_comments_number(); //This returns 2

if (have_comments()):       //This returns "Has not"
    echo "Has";
else:
    echo "Has not";
endif;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you attach the whole `single.php`?

Comment: First, the `endif` function doesn't exist in PHP. Second, if you try this: `if (have_comments() == true)`, what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call [`comments_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) first, otherwise [`have_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_comments) does not work.

Don't ask me why, it's an idiosyncrasy of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the comments array and iterating through it.

```
$comment_array = array_reverse(get_approved_comments($wp_query->post->ID));
    foreach( $comment_array as $comment) {
        var_dump( $comment );
    }
```

FYI, there's also [this great StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)